# Mpdf chrome "Не удалось загрузить документ PDF"

Tags: mpdf, php, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть такая таблица:

[image]

С помощью нее делается отчет наподобие этого:

[image]

Есть такая проблема: в некоторых случаях выходит ошибка в хроме:

> Не удалось загрузить документ PDF

В фаерфоксе такой ошибки нет, и пдф выводится корректно.
Стал смотреть БД, локализовал проблему.
Если в столбце `original_text` больше 34 символов, то выходит такая ошибка.
Однако конкретно данные этого столбца не участвуют в формировании pdf.

Не могу понять, в чем проблема.

**Обновление**

Причина не конкретно в столбце `original_text`. Походу mpdf ограничена в длине строки, которую надо перевести в пдф.
Конкретно в Хроме.
В мозиле он отображается, однако идет предупреждение о "Возможном некорректном выводе".

**Обновление 2**

Еще раз все проверил. Действительно, если в БД есть слишком большие значения (длина строки), то вылетает ошибка эта. Как это исправить, непонятно.